# Merging two files together into one file with git

Tags: git, github, merge, repository, git-merge

I have folder `A_Folder`. Inside that folder there is file `A_File.html`. That folder is in `branch_A` of my repositroy. I have also a `branch_b` which has file `B_File.html`.
How can i merge `A_File.html` and `B_File.html` together to save final code in `A_file.html`?

Comment: yes, But in my case one of the 2 files is not in the same folder. Shall I make it `A_Folder/A_File.html` instead A_File.html  when using that merge algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You've used a technical term, *merge*, in a way it doesn't apply.

You may be thinking of the general (non-Git) verb *to merge*, meaning *to combine*.  If so, the way to do this is simple: obtain the data from the two files you wish to combine into a single file, and then combine that into a single file.

#### Git's idea of merging

The Git form of the verb *to merge* is normally something we apply to entire commits, not to files.  That is, we run:

```
git checkout argument-1
git merge argument-2
```

The two arguments here, *`argument-1`* and *`argument-2`*, identify *commits* (sometimes via branch names, but the branch names are not important).  A commit, in Git, is an entity that holds two things:

- a snapshot of *all* files, and
- some metadata.

The merging process in Git uses the two specified commits to locate a *third* commit, which also contains a snapshot of all files.  The merging process then works on these *three* inputs.

If you would like to merge three inputs, with the three inputs being files, you can use `git merge-file`.  The merging process that Git applies to three input *commits* consists in part of running `git merge-file` on the files from the three commits.  (Before this, the merging process must group the files together in the right way, so that the *correct* three files are merged by each `git merge-file`; we won't cover that here since you aren't concerned with this part.)

#### Your kind of merging

In your case, it sounds like you only have two inputs, not three.  So Git's merging is not what you are interested in.  Hence, you should not use Git to accomplish the merge.

> I have folder `A_Folder` inside that folder there is file `A_File.html` that folder is inside `branch_A` in my repo.

Technically, the name `branch_A` identifies one specific *commit*.  To access this entire commit—making it your current commit—you simply run:

```
git checkout branch_A
```

and now all the files that are in the *last* commit that is on `branch_A` are in your *working tree*, available for you to do whatever you want with.

At this point, it could make sense for you to *copy* `A_Folder/A_File.html` to some file *outside the working tree* (e.g., in `/tmp` or wherever you like on your computer).  You will now have all the data from that file available.

> I have also `branch_b` it has file `B_File.html`

As before, the *name* `branch_b` simply identifies one commit, specifically the *last* commit that is on that branch.  To obtain *all* the files from that commit, you simply run:

```
git checkout branch_b
```

You now have, in your working tree, all the files from that commit.  You can now copy the contents of `B_File.html` *outside of the working tree*, e.g., to `/tmp` if you like.

Now that you have both file-contents, you can choose which commit(s) and/or branches, if any, in your repository should contain the combined contents.  Let's say that the right place to put them is in a new commit on a *new* branch that is to be grown from the *last* commit that is currently on branch `master`.  You would achieve this by doing:

```
git checkout -b newbranch master
```

which will fill your working tree with the files from the last commit on branch `master`, create a new branch name `newbranch`, and set things up so that `newbranch` is the current branch.  New commits you make at this point will add to branch `newbranch`.

(If that's *not* what you want—e.g., if you want to add new commits to your existing `branch_A`—you'd run `git checkout branch_A` here again.  Note how the only thing we're doing in *Git* here is manipulating all the files in the *working tree* while selecting some particular *branch name* to act as the current branch.)

Now that you are on the target branch into which you'd like to write a *new* commit that has some file some name, you can create an empty file with that name:

```
cp /dev/null newfile.html
```

or:

```
: > A_Folder/A.html
```

(Remember, the contents of both files, from the two branch tips, are in `/tmp/A_File.html` and `/tmp/B_File.html`.  So we don't need to *preserve* the *existing* `A_Folder/A.html` content.  We just want an *empty file*.)

You can now simply blat the two `/tmp` files together into a single file.  However, because of the nature of HTML files, you'll probably want to *edit the result* to take out some redundant header and footer lines.  You might also want to re-arrange the contents in some way.  Do all of that with *any programs you like*.  Git is not involved in this process!  The file `newfile.html` or `A_Folder/A.html` is in your *working tree*, not in Git; you can do anything you like to it, with any process you like.

Once the file has the content you want to put in a *new* commit, simply use `git add` to add the updated or new file:

```
git add A_Folder/A_File.html
```

so that you update Git's *index*, i.e., the files (and content) that Git will put into the next commit you make.  Then, run `git commit` to make a new commit, which Git will add to your current branch.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and useful, But in large scale files, Combining the 2 files manually is very hard specially when conflicts are existed. I wanted git to do the combination process and I get notifications about conflicts and where they are. I handle them and  the combination is done. Is there a way to do that?. I read about `merge-file` But I didn't get how can I use it in my case specially when one of the 2 files is not in the same directory. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Conflicts cannot exist without a third input file. Conflicts arise because we compare the third input, the *merge base*, against each of the two branch-tip inputs. These produce two sets of *changes to make to the base*. The conflicts occur if, during the combining of the two changes, one of the pieces of one change (e.g., "add these three lines after line 42") collides with one of the pieces of another change (e.g., "delete lines 42 and 43").

Comment: Without a merge base file, we see only things like "file A says X and Y, file B says X and Z". We don't know if that's because both Y and Z should be added, or Y was initially present and file A is unchanged so that file B is telling us that Y was wrong and should be replaced with Z.